# Add to list at certain index

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with some list manipulation. I take the user's input and search through it: if i find an "=" sign i assume that the string in front of it is the name of a variable , so on the line right above that variable i want to add a new string to the user's input (in this case it is called "tempVAR", doesn't really matter though). I've been trying to do this with StringBuilder but without any success , so i currently am trying to do it with ArrayLists but I am getting stuck at adding new elements to the list. Because of the way list.add(index,string) works , the elements to the right of what i am adding will always add +1 to their index. Is there a way to always know exactly what index i am looking for even after a random number of string has been added? Here is my code so far, if you run it you will see what i mean, instead of "tempVAR" or "tempVar1" being added above the name of the variable they will be added one or to positions in the wrong way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class ToTestStuff {

    static List<String> referenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final String SEMICOLUMN = ";";
    public static final String BLANK = " ";
    public static final String EMPTY = "";
    public static final String LEFT_CURLY = "{";
    public static final char CARRIAGE_RETURN = '\r';
    public static final String CR_STRING = "CARRIAGE_RETURN_AND_NEW_LINE";
    public static final char NEW_LINE = '\n';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        String x = "AGE_X";
        String y = "AGE_Y";
        String z = "AGE_YEARS";
        String t = "P_PERIOD";
        String w = "T_VALID";
        referenceList.add(x);
        referenceList.add(y);
        referenceList.add(z);
        referenceList.add(t);
        referenceList.add(w);

        String text2 = " if ( AGE_YEARS > 35 ) {\r\n"
                + " varX = P_PERIOD ;\r\n"
                + " }\r\n"
                + " if ( AGE_YEARS < 35 ) {\r\n"
                + " varY = T_VALID ;\r\n"
                + " varZ = AGE_Y ;\r\n"
                + " varA = AGE_X ;\r\n"
                + " }";

        detectEquals(text2);
    }

    public static String detectEquals(String text) {
        String a = null;
        // text = text.trim();
        // text = TestSplitting.addDelimiters(text);
        String[] newString = text.split(" ");
        List<String> test = Arrays.asList(newString);
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> signs = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> references = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexesOfStringAndList = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> lastList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<List> minList = new ArrayList<List>();
        String previous = null;
        int index = 0;
        Object obj = new Object();
        List<Integer> referenceValueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> indexPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String b = null;
        int indexOfa = 0;
        // System.out.println("a----> " + test);
        List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList(test);
        for (int i = 0; i < anotherList.size(); i++) {
            a = anotherList.get(i).trim();
            index = strBuilder.length();// - a.length();
            // index = i;
            strBuilder.append(a);   // "=", 3  -  if, 14  - while, 36   , "=", 15
            testList.add(a);


            if (a.equals("if") || a.equals("=")) {
                lastList.add(i);
                indexOfa = i;
                indexesOfStringAndList.put(index, indexOfa);

                refList.add(index);
                indexPosition.add(index);
                if (signs.containsKey(a)) {
                    signs.get(a).add(index);
                } else {
                    signs.put(a, refList);
                }
                refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }

            if (referenceList.contains(a)) {
                indexList.add(index);
                if (references.containsKey(a)) {
                    references.get(a).add(index);
                } else {
                    references.put(a, indexList);
                }
                indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }
        }
        for (String k : references.keySet()) {
            keysList.add(k);
            referenceValueList = references.get(k);
            obj = Collections.min(referenceValueList);
            int is = (Integer) obj;
            ArrayList xx = new ArrayList();
            xx.add(new Integer(is));
            xx.add(k);
            minList.add(xx);

        }

        for (List q : minList) {
            Integer v = (Integer) q.get(0);
            String ref = (String) q.get(1);
            int x = closest(v, indexPosition);
            int lSize = anotherList.size();
            int sizeVar = lSize - test.size();
            int indexOfPx = 0;
            int px = 0;
            if (x != 0) {
                px = indexesOfStringAndList.get(x) - 1;
            } else {
                px = indexesOfStringAndList.get(x);
            }

            if (px == 0) {
                System.out.println("previous when x=0 " +anotherList.get(px+sizeVar));
                anotherList.add(px, "tempVar1=\r\n");

            } else {
                previous = anotherList.get(px + sizeVar);
                System.out.println("previous is---> " + previous + " at position " + anotherList.indexOf(previous));
                anotherList.add(anotherList.indexOf(previous) - 1, "\r\ntempVAR=");

            }
        }
        strBuilder.setLength(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < anotherList.size(); j++) {
            b = anotherList.get(j);
            strBuilder.append(b);
        }
         String stream = strBuilder.toString();
     // stream = stream.replaceAll(CR_STRING, CARRIAGE_RETURN + EMPTY + NEW_LINE);
        System.out.println("after ----> " + stream);
        return stream;

    }

    public static int closest(int of, List<Integer> in) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int closest = of;
        for (int v : in) {
            final int diff = Math.abs(v - of);

            if (diff < min) {
                min = diff;
                closest = v;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
}
```

I've mapped the positions of the "=" and "if" to their positions in the StringBuilder, but these are remnants from when i was trying to use a stringBuilder to do what i said above.

I have been struggling with this for a few days now and still haven't managed to do what i need, i am not sure where i am going wrong. At the moment i am hellbent on making this work as it is (with either lists or string builder) after which , if there is a better way i will look into that and adapt this accordingly.

The addDelimiters() method is a method i created to avoid writing the string as you see it in "String text2" but i took that out for this because it would only clutter my already chaotic code even more :), i don't think it has any relevance to why what i am trying to do is not working.

TLDR: at the line above front of every varX or varY or other "var" i would like to be able to add a string to the list but i think my logic in getting the variable names or in adding to the list is wrong.

Comment: I'm having difficulty working out what this program might be for?

Comment: Believe me I am trying to understand the question. I think I should know the answer. As many other people on SO. The problem is you have not abstracted away the unnecessary information, which confuses I believe not only me. If you try to simplify the question like: I have input of list with strings, I want to manipulate it adding value X in the list before every value Y (this is what I understood of the question) somebody might help you.

Comment: Thank you, i will work on abstracting away the unnecessary info then.

Answer (score 0):

I think we both know that your code is messed up and that you need many more abstractions to make it better. But you could make it work by maintaining an offset variable, lets say "int offset". Each time you insert a string after the initial pass you increment it, and when you access the list you use  it, "list.get(index+offset);". Read up on [Abstract syntax trees.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) , which are a great way to parse and manipulate languages.

Comment: thank you, yes i know the code i pretty messed up. i will work on it a bit and also try out your suggestion with the offset variable